# Как в Vue Js отключить режим "Обновления на месте"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

```
<component v-for="(element,key) in bloks[key_block]" :is="element" :key_block="key_block":key="key"></component>
```

делаю цикл компонентов, цикл нормально отображается, но при попытке удалить один из элементов цикла, удаляется последний, а не выбранный. Если циклить просто html код то эту проблему можно обойти просто добавив `:key`, но при цикле компонентов это не работает, подскажите пожалуйста как быть?

Comment: А как вы удаляете элемент?

Answer (score 0):

пробую, по примеру, но увы

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next" ></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <template v-for="element in components">
        <component :is="element.name" :key="element.id" :title="element.title"></component>
        <button @click="removeComponent(element.id)">удалить {{ element.id }} компонент</button>
    </template>
    <hr>
    <button @click="addComponent">+ компонент</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>

  const ob = {

      data () { return {
          components: [{
              id: 1,
              name: 'element-link',
              title: 'test' }]

      } },
        el: '#app',
      computed: {
          allIds() {
              return this.components.map(x => x.id)
          }
      },
      methods: {
          removeComponent(id) {
              const index = this.components.findIndex(x => x.id === id)
              this.components.splice(index, 1)
          },
          addComponent() {
              const id = this.allIds.length ? Math.max(...this.allIds) + 1 : 1
              this.components.push({
                  id,
                  title: `component ${id}`,
                  name: 'test'
              })
          }
      }
  };
  const app = Vue.createApp(ob);
  const test = app.component('test',  {
      props: ['title'],
      template: `
    <div>Компонент - {{ title }} <input type="text"></div>
  `
  })

  app.mount('body');

</script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.

Comment: Не используйте поле ответов для уточнений вопроса, [правте сам вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1325433/217579) .